# Finding first n primes efficiently

Tags: algorithm, testing, primes, brute-force

I have a  brute-force algorithm that takes an input n, and displays the first n prime numbers. The code works, but I also have to answer this question:

> Give the number of test items that would be required to assure correctness.

Is there a way to calculate this? Would I technically need to test every possible int value (all 2 billion possibilities)?

Comment: Do you want to test the prime-ness of the numbers generated by your algorithm? If yes, for each `n` you need to go from 2 to `sqrt(n)`. So total number of items will be `sqrt(X)` where `X` is the largest prime you have found. 

You may also need to test that you have not missed any prime. So probably for any number less than `X` you need to find a non-trivial divisor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a number *n*, and need to check if it is a prime, there are more efficient ways than brute force.

One way would be to use the [Miller-Rabin Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test). The Miller-Rabin test either finds proof that a number is a composite, or it does not such find proof (it does not directly prove that a number is a prime). So the scheme would be:

1. run Miller-Rabin at most *k* times (or until it found that the number is a composite)
2. if Miller-Rabin claims it is a possible prime, perform a brute force check

Miller-Rabin runs [as follows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Concepts). Obviously, you need test only for odd *n*, and so *n - 1* is even, and you can write *n - 1 = 2<sup>s</sup>d* for some positive *s* and positive odd *d*. Randomly choose an *a* from the range *(0, n - 1)*. If *a<sup>d</sup> ≠ 1 | n* and *a<sup>2<sup>r</sup>d</sup> ≠ -1 | n*, then *n* is a composite.

If *n* is a composite, the probability that *k* iterations of Miller-Rabin will not prove it so, is less than *4<sup>-k</sup>*. Note that by the [Prime Number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), primes are scarce.

The computational-complexity of *k* applications of Miller-Rabin, even with a naive implementation, [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Computational_complexity), is *O(k log<sup>3</sup>(n))*.